# Integrate CRM or Webapp behind Joomla site

Tags: php, security, joomla, user-management

Im trying to figure out how to do this but i cant seem to find a solution.

Ive writen a crm/client management software with php/sql and java.
It works ok with it's own database etc  and it's written from scratch, all handwritten code.

What i want to do is use a joomla site as a frontend for navigation + visitors to browse the public parts etc

Plus  for two different types of registered users (free and payed) to be able to access some parts of the webapp mostly different .php files

Where should i start looking?
I could maybe integrate some parts (like profile management etc) inside html modules in joomla pages.
I could also have Links inside the joomla navigation that will point to the php files so that they are displayed as whole.
but, i need to be able  to protect those php's with the joomla user accounts, so that even if someone had the link could not visit them unless logged in

Any ideas? pointers? guides?
sorry for being kind of vague, but im really lost and dont know how to begin

Thanx in advance

Addition: Isn't there some way i can force joomla to create a blank page?
No menus, no css, just the html and body tags, then i could `include` my whole php files in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Joomla Api located [here](http://api.joomla.org/li_Joomla-Platform.html)

This documentation is all you need.

Comment: joomla api would require me to rewrite the whole app?   or can a php "website" be integrated there?

Comment: You can use the api to "talk" to joomla. Make session, query the database. This is the cleanest and easiest approach to go. 

Maybe the better too, because that way the code we be more clean.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to pull your crm in via an iframe. You could create an article and put html (i.e. iframe) in there, or alternatively you could create a Joomla component that does the same thing.

To address the issue about showing restricted pages to users, you could use Joomla's native user management to limit who may see what pages (if you place iframes in an article). Likewise you will be able to do the same process when developing with Joomla's MVC framework.

Comment: that was kind of my first thought, but i was afraid it would slow everything down... plus the aesthetics would get messed up

Comment: Well then your only solution is to rewrite using Joomla's MVC framework.